# What is the correct way to handle an event in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen two different ways to aproach it:

```
$('#element').on('click', function(){
    /* do stuff */
});
```

Or:

```
 $('#element').click(function(){
    /* do stuff */
});
```

which is the correct/better way?

Comment: They are both identical. If you [check the source](https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.click), `click()` calls `on('click', fn)` internally anyway. There are some who say you should only use `on()`, but that is purely a preference. There is no logical reason for it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the only difference is that using .on() you can set a namespace to the event. Example: .on('click.somename', function() {})

Comment: True, however I was talking more in the context of usage in the OPs example

Comment: it is better to use `on` because you can then use [events' namespaceing](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/): `.on("click.fun", cb)`...

Answer (score 0):

.On() function was introduced in Jquery 1.7, it is better and more preferred method to call the event. whereas if you are looking for backward compatibility then choose the other one.